# Angular 4 - Get Value from JSON by Key

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get the value by the key of this json. 
The key is description and i want it in my console.log, i don't really get how to get this value, the filtering before worked fine.

```
{
    "id": "149",
    "description": "Try"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const dummy = {
  id : '1',
  description : 'Wow awesome'
};

console.log(dummy.description);

//-------------------------------------

const descData = dummy.description;

console.log(descData);
```

`variableName['description']` or `variableName.description`

Comment: But when i make: const test = ['description']. console.log got -> undefinied. Thats why i open up this threat

Comment: My use-case looks like, i got a big json file about 5000 lines long. Since one hour I made filters to get this tiny snippet above and now I want to get in my const the value of the key "description" to fill up my table on my html template.

Comment: @muelleste , please check the snippet, i think that will clear your doubts

Comment: console.log('treeNodes:' + JSON.stringify(treeNodes));
console.log(treeNodes.description);                                                               treeNodes:"{\"id\":\"147\",\description\":\"Try\"}"   test.component.ts:42:13
undefined . That's my result

Comment: there is one extra double quotes after description , please check that.

Comment: When i call my object over console.log(treeNodes) thats the Output:{"id":"147","description":"Try"}

Comment: try `treeNodes.description` OR `var data = JSON.parse(treeNodes); console.log(data.description);`

Comment: @muelleste , did that help ?

Comment: that worked for me, with parse. I always used stringfy, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

First You need to parse it using JSON.parse. Then using . or [] you can access. For Ex:-

```
var a = '{
    "id": "149",
    "description": "Try"
}'
```

b = JSON.parse(a)

b['description'] or b.description
FOr more reference you can study [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)